# Можно ли удалить все кроме корневой папки c помощью del?

Tags: node.js, файлы, gulp

Мне надо очистить папку от файлов и подпапок с помощью `gulp`. Использую для этого модуль `del`, но он удаляет всю папку, когда пишу путь к ней:

```
let fs = requare('fs'),
gulp = requare('gulp'),
del = requare('del');

gulp.task("wp",  () => {
    fs.readdir(project.build.php, (err) => {
        if (!err) del('./temp/')
```

А если пишу в качестве пути `'./temp/*'`, то del вообще ничего не удаляет. Можно ли как-то удалить файлы и подпапки в temp используя del или другой модуль? Просто не хочется циклом пробегать по папке и удалять через `fs.unlink`, так как файлов и подпапок много.

Comment: а вы пробовали читать документацию к пакету del?

Comment: “You have to explicitly ignore the parent directories too“ и всё такое прочее, для чего пишут тагументацию

Comment: Может, проще удалить папку с содержимым через `fs.rm()`, а потом создать пустую?